# How to prevent buttons from multiplying?

Tags: jquery, button

I am a complete jQuery beginner, however, I am trying to create a piece of code that would show a description when a thumbnail picture is clicked. I managed to make it work so that it shows the respect description belonging to each picture, and create a functional close button.

But when I close the description using the thumbnail (there's a toggle method used), the button multiplies if I open that picture's description again.

I know that it does this because the code appends the button every time the description window is opened, but can't figure out how to prevent this. I tried looking for a possible solution but didn't come up with anything similar to my problem..

Here is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnails li img').click(function() {
        var thumbSplit = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
            identName = $('#cont_' + thumbSplit[1]);

        identName.toggle();
        $('.content-window').not(identName).hide();

        var closeButton = $('<button class="close">close</div>');
        closeButton.appendTo(identName.not(':hidden'));
        closeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.content-window').hide();
            closeButton.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thosetinydreams/4r8QP/4/

Comment: My inital thought is that when your buttons multiply you need to keep your male buttons in a separate cage from your female buttons. Oh wait... *cough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The close button is dynamically created each time you click one of the images.  There are a few ways to avoid this issue.

- Each time you're in the click event, remove any existing buttons before adding one.
- Don't add the buttons dynamically - just add them in the html.

I lean towards the second, since it's a lot cleaner.

Let me see if I can fix up the fiddle...

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5H6ts/3/) is a fiddle for moving the buttons.  I did the changes I mentioned, and moved the `$('.close').click` function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.thumbnails li img').click(function() {
    var thumbSplit = $(this).attr('id').split('_'),
        identName = $('#cont_' + thumbSplit[1]);

    identName.toggle();
    $('.content-window').not(identName).hide();
});
$('.close').on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents('.content-window').hide();
        closeButton.remove();
    });
});
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5H6ts/4/) is a fiddle for my first suggestion, which really isn't so bad.  In your click function, I check to see if there are any existing .close classes.  If there are, I just append it to the area you want, so it and its click event are only created once:

```
$('.thumbnails li img').click(function() {
    var thumbSplit = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        // descrSplit = $('.descriptions').find('.content-window').attr('id').split('_'),
        identName = $('#cont_' + thumbSplit[1]);

    identName.toggle();
    $('.content-window').not(identName).hide();

    var closeButton = $('.close');
    if (closeButton.length == 0) {
        closeButton = $('<button class="close">close</div>');
        closeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parents('.content-window').hide();
            closeButton.remove();
        });
    }
    closeButton.appendTo(identName.not(':hidden'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

I opted for the dynamic solution as there are going to be quite a lot of pictures and I didn't want to manually add the button code to each of them.

Just out of curiosity, how would the first solution removing the buttons before adding them look like? I tried it and it didn't work for some reason, so I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: @thosetinydreams No problem.  Either solution I posted should work ok for you.  In fact, at this point, the one where you don't add it to the html each time seems more efficient.  Check my edit for having only one close button.

Answer (score 1):

just change this line

```
 closeButton.remove();
```

to this

```
$(this).remove();
```